# Display local time zone abbreviation using DateFormatter

Tags: ios, swift

I have a DateFormatter that outputs the date in the format `"2:00pm`, `Thu 18 Oct"`:

```
static func scheduleFormatter() -> DateFormatter {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.amSymbol = "am"
    dateFormatter.pmSymbol = "pm"
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mma, EE dd MMM"
    return dateFormatter
}
```

I need to add in the local time zone abbreviation of the user so that the string appears like `"2:00 pm GMT`, `Thu 18 Oct"`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [Unicode Date Formatting Patterns](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns):

Probably you want the pattern `v`:

> The short generic non-location format. Where that is unavailable, falls back to the generic location format ("VVVV"), then the short localized GMT format as the final fallback.

or `z`:

> The short specific non-location format. Where that is unavailable, falls back to the short localized GMT format ("O").

Note that time zone names are connected to language and setting `posix` locale will probably break that.

You could also ask for the abbreviation directly and include it in your format explicitly:

```
"h:mma, '\(TimeZone.current.abbreviation() ?? "")' EE dd MMM"
```

Answer (score 0):

To display the time zone you can simply add "zzz" in your dateFormat string. For example: "h:mma zzz, EE dd MMM"

Answer (score -1):

public static Date getCurrentTimeStampDate(){

```
String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat(""yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")).getTime());  
    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat(""yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {
        return formater.parse(currentDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {


        return null;  
    }
}
```

Comment: A Java solution wasn’t asked for. If it had been, suggesting `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat` is very poor advice. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. Formatting and parsing back are two redundant operations with no gain that I can see. As an aside there are a couple of typos in your code, so it cannot be compiled.